# CRUD in Android Studio with Retrofit

Tags: php, android, android-studio, retrofit

I am doing an Android app that include 2 activitys, one is the main activity and the other is to show the data in a listview.. My answer is How can I make de DELETE part of the CRUD, selecting one of the items in the listView?? For the insert,update and show the info I use Retrofit and the files that make the consults to the database are in PHP..

Comment: Use @Delete annotation in retrofit for your method.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that retrofit had that.. thanks